# How do I make a hyperlink within a Word document to another place in the same document?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

(It seems like this must have already been asked, but I'm not finding it.)

I have a Word 2010 document, and I want to make a link in one part of the document pointing to another part of the same document.  I have a table that needs to be filled out, and in the instructions about the table, I want to link to it.  That way, they can easily get to the table referenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create the place you want to link to as a "Top of Document", "Heading", or "Bookmark".

In the screenshot, I created 123 as a "Heading", and then right-clicked my "Test" text and clicked`Hyperlink>Place in this document`, and you will see 123 there. To do it as a bookmark, highlight the target text, and go to `Insert>bookmark`, and it will also then show in the Hyperlink area.

[image]

Comment: I finally figured it out, right after asking.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the bookmark tip, was trying to figure out how to create a link with no header!

Answer (score 0):

Right click and select "hyperlink" option on the text where you want to create hyperlink, which opens a new dialogue box. Select the second option in the left had side "Place in this Document", which gives you the content table. Select the appropriate section, then click OK.