# Word missing headings in insert hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-word

I've created a style `My_Heading` that is based on `Heading 2`, and I have a lot of `My_Heading` titles.
I want to link some of them. I go to `Insert > Link > Place in this document`, but my headings didn't appear. (*If I place a bookmark, then it appears, but I don't want to use bookmarks*).

So I wonder why my heading styles are missing when placing a link, but normal Headings works ? What's the difference since my style is based on heading style?

I am using MS Word 2019 on Windows 10

Already checked

- [How to hyperlink within document](https://superuser.com/questions/532357/how-to-hyperlink-within-document)
- [How do I make a hyperlink within a Word document to another place in the same document?](https://superuser.com/questions/315405/how-do-i-make-a-hyperlink-within-a-word-document-to-another-place-in-the-same-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think custom styles never worked this way (at least since Word 2010). You should use original Heading styles to take advantage of this functionality.

See [Microsoft forum thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/custom-heading-styles-do-not-show-as-headers-in/a3f0ab4c-a119-40b9-8b5b-c02f4580477b) for details.

Comment: Sooo sad ... It seems the only way is bookmarks or build-in headings. I asked that, because I always make custom styles to preserve original headings.